# Parallel analog to torch.nn.Sequential container

Tags: pytorch

Just wondering, why I can't find subj in `torch.nn`? nn.Sequential is pretty convinient, it allows to define networks in one place, clear and visual, but restricted to very simple ones! With parallel analog (and litle help of "identity" nodes for residual connections) it forms a complete method to construct any feedforward net combinatorial way. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, maybe it shouldn't be in standard module collection, just because it can be defined really simple:

```
class ParallelModule(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ParallelModule, self).__init__( *args )

    def forward(self, input):
        output = []
        for module in self:
            output.append( module(input) )
        return torch.cat( output, dim=1 )
```

Inheriting "Parallel" from "Sequential" is ideologically bad, but works well.
Now one can define networks like pictured, with following code:
[image: Network image by torchviz:]

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(  1, 32, 3, padding=1 ),        nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d( 32, 64, 3, padding=1 ),        nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d( 3, stride=2 ),              nn.Dropout2d( 0.25 ),

            ParallelModule(
                nn.Conv2d(  64, 64, 1 ),
                nn.Sequential( 
                    nn.Conv2d(  64, 64, 1 ),          nn.ReLU(),
                    ParallelModule(
                        nn.Conv2d(  64, 32, (3,1), padding=(1,0) ),
                        nn.Conv2d(  64, 32, (1,3), padding=(0,1) ),
                    ),
                ),
                nn.Sequential( 
                    nn.Conv2d(  64, 64, 1 ),          nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Conv2d(  64, 64, 3, padding=1 ), nn.ReLU(),
                    ParallelModule(
                        nn.Conv2d(  64, 32, (3,1), padding=(1,0) ),
                        nn.Conv2d(  64, 32, (1,3), padding=(0,1) ),
                    ),
                ),
                nn.Sequential( 
                    #PrinterModule(),
                    nn.AvgPool2d( 3, stride=1, padding=1 ),
                    nn.Conv2d(  64, 64, 1 ),
                ),
            ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d( 256, 64, 1 ),                  nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Conv2d( 64, 128, 3, padding=1 ),       nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d( 3, stride=2 ),              nn.Dropout2d( 0.5 ),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear( 4608, 128 ),                   nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(  128,  10 ),                   nn.LogSoftmax( dim=1 ),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net.forward( x )
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for replying to an old question. Found [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36459) github thread, seems they aren't adding an nn.Parallel anytime soon. If you're interested, I made a [tiny pip-installable library](https://github.com/Ilykuleshov/pytorch-toolz) for this exact purpose with a small collection of functools-like layers (Map, Filter, Reduce). Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, but are those elements like Map, Filter and Reduce applied in a parallel fashion? That means, that they are parallized on e.g. a GPU.

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider I haven't seen any pytorch code parallelized in the manner you speak of, there has always been an underlying loop. At the moment I have no clue how to do this correctly :(. There is actually a discussion on this topic in the github thread I attached to my answer, it seems that they also couldn't find a way to parallelize this code. So, at the moment, this library just gives an alternative way for creating modules, which require parallel logic (such as Resblock).

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider Did some research, most CUDA calls are asynchronous, see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/understanding-asynchronous-execution/19468/3. This means, that my loop-based implementation is actually somewhat parallelized as is: control is returned to CPU without waiting for previous module to finish calculations. From what I've seen, further parallelization is very tricky and rarely attempted.

Comment: Great job! Could you provide some use cases, to show usefulness, for example, can one construct `RNN` with `LSTM` \ `GRU` cell using `Reduce`? And `README.md` certainly needs attention, some words about the idea at least.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov Thanks for your insights, sure thing! Will get on that right now)

Comment: Ok, In general, good idea that you had and thank you for sharing your package! I will write if there is a hint for a solution but probably, you would have to write a custom CUDA kernel that assigns each model to parts of the CUDA and is then imported to PyTorch.

Comment: Oh, good. One more suggestion: turn on `discussions` in your github project page settings.